# Switch kernels from grub menu Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, kernel

I am trying to switch kernels from the grub menu (GNU GRUB version 2.06).
When I hold shift and press escape to enter the menu, this is what it looks like

```sh
grub>
```

and it wants me to type.

How can I switch kernels from here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) Shift *or* Escape when booting, depending on whether or not your system is UEFI.

Comment: no, I can get there I just don't know how to switch kernels once I'm there.

Comment: again, I can already access the menu, I just don't know what to do after I get there to switch kernels.

Comment: @Nmath I can't seem to get that menu, just boots into bios every time

Answer (score 0):

The menu in the question is the wrong menu, I was able to get to the correct one by spamming both shift keys while the computer was booting.